# How to abort call in java script?

Tags: javascript

Suppose,

I have shown 5 options on my page. I called same function on each option click. but, Now i want to abort first call when user click second times.

How can i do this??

would be grateful for help..

Comment: can you post your example code

Comment: If you have a big, long running function being trigger on click this could be a little tricky as javascript is not multithreaded.

Comment: Yes I agree with Oliver... I would just disable other options while function runs and show some "Wait please.." :-)

Comment: post code or explain clearly what you really want I don't get it... You cannot cancel a function call if the function has been executed already...

Comment: @Oliver it is with HTML5 and web workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've given, what you're asking for can't be done as JavaScript is single-threaded.